# What's the syntax of calling a stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Little help needed here. I'm new to Oracle and i'm not understaning the the syntax of calling a store procedure that has a single in-out parameter. Any example please?

Answer (score 5):

```
-- procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (param IN OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   NULL;
END;


-- call procedure
DECLARE
   var   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   test_proc (var);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous PL/SQL block to do this:

```
BEGIN
  do_something();
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the tag I assume you are asking to invoke a oracle SP from SQL plus...

Say you have an SP with name test_me then from sql plus

SQL> execute test_me (parameters_value)

Comment: This will fail with "PLS-00363: expression 'parameters_value' cannot be used as an assignment target "

Answer (score 0):

{[?=]call procedure_name[([parameter][,[parameter]]...)]}

for example

{call InsertOrder(10)}